# How do I resample a Dataframe with average weighting each value on a time ratio until next value according to the Dateframe's Datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

How can I resample a Dataframe's column, that has float values, with the average, of the values within the resampling period, weighting each value on the ratio of:

- time that, according to the Dateframe's Datetime index, goes by until reaching the following value within the same resampling period
  divided by
- the time length of the resampling period?

The input Dataframe has one resamplable column and a Datetime Index.

Comment: Please provide sample input and sample output for your question in text format

Comment: Hello, I just added a screenshot with an example.

Comment: I just rephrased my question from scratch on the link mentioned above. I posted the question twice without being aware of that. Therefore this post could be removed now if administrators consider that is a good idea.